# Access array[][]...[] element with N "[]" automatically

Tags: python, arrays, n-dimensional

First I apologize if this question has already been asked. I've search for it but found nothing.

Given the following code :

```
RHO = RHOarray(D,nbInter)
    print(RHO)
    for k in range(N):
        for l in range(D):
            j=0
            Coord=[0 for i in range(D)]
            while ((X[k][l]>mini+(j+1)*step) and (j<nbInter)):
                j+=1
            Coord[l]+=j 
            RHO[ ]
for k in range(len(RHO)):
    RHO[k]/=N
return RHO
```

RHO is a D-dimensions array, of size nbInter. (RHOarray is a function that creates such an array). The problem is that according to D's value, I'd need to access RHO[n] if D = 1, RHO[n][m] if D = 2 ... RHO[n][m]...[whatever indice] as D increases. Every indices would actually be Coord[0], Coord[1]... and so on, so I know what I have to put into each indices. To make the question "simpler" : how can I do so the number of "[...]" after RHO increases as much as D does ?

I hope I've been clear. I'm french and even in my native language it's still tricky to explain. Thanks in advance

ps The initial code is longer but I don't think there's need to show it entirely.

Comment: You could probably illuminate your problem by providing some sample input with the desired ouput.

Comment: So given something like `Coord = [1,2,3,4,5]`, you want `RHO[1][2][3][4][5]`?

Comment: @chepner yes, exactly. But Coord's size depends directly on D, so does the number of indices after RHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do something like

```
 indices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 value = X

 for i in indices:
     value = value[i]
 print(value)
```

If `X` is a numpy array, you could directly do
`X[(1,2,3)]` instead of `X[1, 2, 3]` or `X[1][2][3]`

Comment: I don't understand how that solves the problem... I don't need to print anything, nor to change an indice's value. But I need the amount of indices to change according to an argument.

Comment: Printing is not the point. what the for loop does is create the value `X[1][2][3][4][5]` from an array of indices

Comment: The temporary name `value` "iterates" over the nested object. You don't need to generate the syntactic expression in order to get the value.

Comment: @chepner: what??

Comment: @blue_note That was meant to explain to Tiranyk that the loop calculates the expression he wants, whether or not it literally constructs the equivalent "hard-coded" expression.

Comment: @chepner: aah, ok

Comment: @blue_note thanks a lot for your editing, I understood.